# Android SQLite get specific rows using LIKE clause

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database with 2 tables. In `raw_data` table I have some columns (latitude, longitude, time, ...) and in `results` table I want to store results from calculations of `raw_data`, but I want to calculate them base on time. (= for example I want to get only rows from today at 12:00 to 12:59, calculate them and save in `results` table).
I wanted to use LIKE clause. So I wrote this code at `Locations.java` (class, where I'm working with database):

```
public Cursor getLocationsByHour(String specificHour) 
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();       
        return db.query(TABLE1_NAME, columns_T1, COLUMN_T1_TIMECEST_RAW + " LIKE '" + specificHour + "%'", null, null, null, null, null);}
```

Where:

```
TABLE1_NAME is a protected static final String TABLE1_NAME = "raw_data";    
columns_T1 is a public static final String[] columns_T1 = {some columns names};
COLUMN_T1_TIMECEST_RAW is a public static final String COLUMN_T1_TIME_RAW = "time";    
specificHour is a i.e. 01. 06. 2013 12
```

I'm calling `getLocationsByHour()` from method `fillResultsTable()` at `Locations.java`:

```
    public String fillResultsTable() 
        {
            String specificHour = "01. 06. 2013 12";  //hard coded for test purposes        
            String message;

            try {

                Cursor dbLocation = getLocationsByHour(specificHour);

                //HERE IS CODE WITH CALLING CALCULATIONS METHODS

                message = "OK";

            } catch (Exception e) {
                message = e.toString();         
            }
            return message;
        }
```

And at `ToolsActivity.java` I'm calling `fillResultsTable()` at `button1Click()` method.

But this code returns ALL rows from `raw_data`, not specific rows.

What I did wrong?

PS: Sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what you have written, I assume that COLUMN_T1_TIMECEST_RAW is a **string**. have you checked the data to ensure that it contains what you expected ?

---

If (as I suspect) the data is actually a long value (time in milliseconds, represented as an integer in sqlite), you need to use ">" and "<" or "between" (and Calendar.getTimeInMillis()) to limit the query to the selected range (LIKE is **only** for string comparison)

eg:

```
private static final long DAY= 1000*60*60*24; // milliseconds in a day
Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar();
mycal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
/* do day, month, minute, etc*/
 ....
long time = mycal.getTimeInMillis();
SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();       
String[] args = {Long.toString(time), Long.toString(time+DAY-1)}; // 24 hr - 1ms timespan
return db.query(TABLE1_NAME, columns_T1, COLUMN_T1_TIMECEST_RAW + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", args, null, null, null, null);}
```

OR

```
return db.query(TABLE1_NAME, columns_T1, COLUMN_T1_TIMECEST_RAW + ">? AND "+COLUMN_T1_TIMECEST_RAW +"<?", args, null, null, null, null);}
```

---

if COLUMN_T1_TIMECEST_RAW is actually stored as a string in sqlite and you wish to progress this further, it would be useful if you posted :

a) the actual table definition code
b) some of the data (a few lines)

also, I would recommend :

1) if you want to keep COLUMN_T1_TIMECEST_RAW as a string; convert your tables to FTS3 ([documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)) and use MATCH

2) if your timerange >1970 and <2036 store the time as "milliseconds since epoch" and adjust code accordingly

3) store the time as an INTEGER YYYYMMDDHHmm  eg 201306011259 and compare 201306010000 <= time < 201306012359    (m + h*100 + d*10000 + mon*1000000 + year*10000000). use MODULO and integer division to separate out the parts

4) store the time as a REAL   ( YYYYMMDD.frac ) more or less the same as #3 but a bit less efficient IMHO

Comment: I forgot to write, that I have at `raw_data` table both representations. Time in miliseconds and time in human-readable format in String (using simple date format). So first column is `_id` (ie. 1), second is `time` in miliseconds (ie. 1367774109000; data type `long`), third is `timeCEST` (ie. 05. 05. 2013 19:15:09; data type `String`) and some other columns.

Comment: OK, I will try to use `return db.query(TABLE1_NAME, columns_T1, COLUMN_T1_TIMECEST_RAW + ">? AND "+COLUMN_T1_TIMECEST_RAW +"<?", args, null, null, null, null);}` with miliseconds column and if it will work, I will check your answer as accepted. Thank you for now.

Comment: also, try printing out the sql before running it (sql="....";Log.d("",sql); db.query(table, columns, sql,....);    ).      BTW, beware of CST/CET changeover.